# Viewing enqueued messages with hawtio

Tags: activemq-classic, hawtio

I'm trying to use hawtio to view some enqueued topics in ActiveMQ.

But when I click on view messages, I get a blank list as output (even though I know the contents are not blank).

This is the error message I get when I browse around my localhost on /8080/hawtio/, so I'm guessing something regarding this is causing it.

Failed to get a response! { "error_type": "javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException", "error": "javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException : org.fusesource.insight:type=LogQuery", "status": 404, "request": { "operation": "logResultsSince", "mbean": "org.fusesource.insight:type=LogQuery", "arguments": [ 0 ], "type": "exec" }, "stacktrace": "javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException: org.fusesource.insight:type=LogQuery\n\tat com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.getMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1095)\n\tat com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.getMBeanInfo(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1375)\n\tat com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.getMBeanInfo(JmxMBeanServer.java:920)\n\tat org.jolokia.handler.ExecHandler.extractMBeanParameterInfos(ExecHandler.java:167)\n\tat org.jolokia.handler.ExecHandler.extractOperationTypes(ExecHandler.java:133)\n\tat org.jolokia.handler.ExecHandler.doHandleRequest(ExecHandler.java:84)\n\tat org.jolokia.handler.ExecHandler.doHandleRequest(ExecHandler.java:40)\n\tat org.jolokia.handler.JsonRequestHandler.handleRequest(JsonRequestHandler.java:89)\n\tat org.jolokia.backend.MBeanServerExecutorLocal.handleRequest(MBeanServerExecutorLocal.java:109)\n\tat org.jolokia.backend.MBeanServerHandler.dispatchRequest(MBeanServerHandler.java:102)\n\tat org.jolokia.backend.LocalRequestDispatcher.dispatchRequest(LocalRequestDispatcher.java:91)\n\tat org.jolokia.backend.BackendManager.callRequestDispatcher(BackendManager.java:388)\n\tat org.jolokia.backend.BackendManager.handleRequest(BackendManager.java:150)\n\tat org.jolokia.http.HttpRequestHandler.executeRequest(HttpRequestHandler.java:197)\n\tat org.jolokia.http.HttpRequestHandler.handlePostRequest(HttpRequestHandler.java:131)\n\tat org.jolokia.jvmagent.JolokiaHttpHandler.executePostRequest(JolokiaHttpHandler.java:195)\n\tat org.jolokia.jvmagent.JolokiaHttpHandler.handle(JolokiaHttpHandler.java:143)\n\tat com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:77)\n\tat sun.net.httpserver.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:83)\n\tat com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:80)\n\tat sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange$LinkHandler.handle(ServerImpl.java:677)\n\tat com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:77)\n\tat sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange.run(ServerImpl.java:649)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)\n" }

Comment: What version of ActiveMQ and hawtio are you using? And how do you run ActiveMQ, eg standalone with bin/activemq or some other way?

Answer (score 2):

Incidentally ActiveMQ doesn't support browsing of topics; only queues

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to upgrade to hawt.io 1.2M27, which fixes this issue.  1.2M26 was assuming the log query was always installed, M27 removed it from the default.

Answer (score 1):

Also we don't yet support all activemq message types, there's an open issue for that -> https://github.com/hawtio/hawtio/issues/655

So if your messages are not text messages this could be why you're not seeing the message body.